# Maven - Referring for properties file in subfolder not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3

In my Maven project , I have a spring config file. It refers to a set of properties files. Property files are available under a config folder in src/main/resources. Spring config files are available under src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/. During installation, all these files are available under target/classes as per Maven standards.

Now in spring config XML : if I refer to properties files as below its not working

> property name="location" value="classpath:test.properties" 
>                          or
>       property name="location" value="classpath*:test.properties"

I am forced to provide the subfolder to actually refer to the necessary properties file. Something like this.

> property name="location" value="classpath:***config***/test.properties"

Is this how Maven expects us to look for properties file? Please clarify and let me know what is the best way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This is a Spring behaviour and has little to do with Maven. I would change the question to ask where Spring expects to find the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now!!! I have to explicitly mention the subfolder as a new resource folder. By default maven classpath will point to src/main/resources. If we want to have a property files and XML files in specific sub folder, it should be mentioned explicitly in the pom.xml as a separate "build" tag as follows.

```
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*.xml</include>
          <include>*.properties</include>
        </includes>            
    </resource>
```

Comment: Looks like a hack to me, especially adding a subfolder of src/main/resources, which I suspect will cause the configuration files to be duplicated. Something like <directory>${basedir}/src/main/config</directory> would make more sense.

Comment: what you're doing there, AFAIK, is that you copy form the subfolder to parent folder (and duplicate your configs like said). You should rather fix the Spring configuration.

Comment: I dont see any duplication of config files. Only difference is the final classpath has all the files copied to the parent folder and there are no subfolders anymore. Also in our project is we have around 80 spring config XMLs in our project and its bound to grow in the coming days as well. I would need these files in the parent folder only for the unit/integration testing. Fixing each one of the junit test cases to look for our appropriate spring config file and as well the properties files in the actual spring config files will be very tedious. Can we achieve this in any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring `classpath` refers to the `classes` folder. If your configuration files are under a subfolder of `classes`, `config` in your case, you need to specify the sub folder name. Therefore, that's why the following works:

> property name="location" value="classpath:config/test.properties"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Will. Actually we are currently doing an upgrade from ant build to Maven build. In old environment its working pretty fine. So I think this has more to do with the Maven rather than Spring.

Comment: Does the structure of the classes folder look different now that it was with Ant?

Comment: Yes. We have split the project into the multiple modules. Java files are in a separate module. All the config files are moved to a separate module. Java module is set up with the dependency to module containing the config files. But other than the modularization, the config files folder structure is still the same.

Comment: Its working now!!! I have to explicitly mention the subfolder as a new resource folder. By default maven classpath will point to src/main/resources. If we want to have a property files and XML files in specific sub folder, it should be mentioned explicitly in the pom.xml.
      <build>
        <resources>  
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
         <includes>
           <include>*.xml</include>
           <include>*.properties</include>
         </includes>            
        </resource>
       </resources>
      </build>